# Running equation in javascript object

Tags: javascript

Is it at all possible to run an equation inside an object? An example of what I'd like to achieve is:

```
var taxes = {
    gst: '0.10',
};

var prices = {
    first_key: '437.95',
    total_key: parseFloat(prices.first_key * taxes.gst).toFixed(2),
    .......
    },
};
```

Or am I going to have to run it through as a function?

```
var prices = {
    total_key: function() { return parseFloat(prices.first_key * taxes.gst).toFixed(2);}
}
```

If at all, is it possible to do it as the first option?

Cheers.

Comment: Why didn't you test it?

Comment: The expression in the first example will be executed when you do the `var prices` assignment, not every time you access the element.

Comment: There's no point in calling `parseFloat()` on the result of a multiplication. You should call `parseFloat` on the strings that are in the properties _before_ multiplying them.

Comment: Keep in mind that using a getter will not work in IE8

Comment: Have tested it, it seems the answers solve the issue I was facing. Also thanks @Barmar for that note!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript object getters.

```
var prices = {
    first_key: '437.95',
    get total_key(){return parseFloat(this.first_key * taxes.gst).toFixed(2)},
    .......
    },
};
```

then to access value,

```
prices.total_key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a `getter function`, which pretty much is a function, but behaves as a property. That could look like

```
var prices = {
    first_key: '437.95',
    get total_key() {
        return (parseFloat( this.first_key ) * parseFloat( taxes.gst ) ).toFixed( 2 );
    }
};
```

Now you can just access

```
prices.total_key;
```

and you get the result.